# Complex MYSQL SELECT help needed

Tags: mysql, case

I've been trying to get my code to work exactly right, it works for the most part perfectly, with one exception, It's sort of hard to explain in words, so I will try to show you what I'm dealing with.

First off, here's my MYSQL QUERY so far, (which all needs to stay pretty much the same, or at least accomplish the same thing this does)

```
$notificationsq = mysql_query("SELECT  N.*, P.*, 
  (CASE 
    WHEN 
    (N.action = 2 AND N.state = 0) THEN 1 
    ELSE N.state 
  END) AS state  
  FROM 
  notifications N, 
  posts P 
  WHERE N.userID='$session' AND  
       (N.action='1' OR N.action='2') AND 
        N.uniqueID=P.id AND 
        P.state='0' 
  GROUP BY N.uniqueID 
  ORDER BY N.state ASC, N.date DESC 
");
```

Here's my table setup for notifications (the code relating posts table is irrelevant for my problem)
http://i43.tinypic.com/2wd6phl.png

What each row represents (only the rows that aren't self explanatory):

- uniqueID is the ID of the post that is to be notified about.
- action is what kind of notification it is. 1 is new post, 2 is new comment on post.
- state is whether or not the notification has been read or not. 0 is unread, 1 is read.

right now "state" only returns for posts (action = 1) that are unread (state = 0) however I want it to return "state" as 0 for the post if any of the posts get a new comment.

it's like, 
IF(action==2 AND state==0 WHERE uniqueID==uniqueID){state = 0}

Comment: Format and indent your SQL statement properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

how about this:

```
SELECT
    `N`.*,
    `P`.*,
    `N`.`state` AS `state`
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            `notifications`
        WHERE
            `userID`='$session'
        AND
            (
                    (
                            `action`='1'
                        AND
                            `state` = 0
                    )
                OR
                    `action`='2'
            )
        ORDER BY
            `state` ASC,
            `date` DESC
    ) AS `N`,
    `posts` AS `P`
WHERE
    `N`.`uniqueID`=`P`.`id`
GROUP BY
    `N`.`uniqueID`
```

Comment: There's not error with this, however it does exactly as it does now. thanks though.

Comment: Oh wow, this actually seems to work perfectly, and you managed to reduce the code greatly, EXCEPT it doesn't return notifications that have been read, as it did before.

Comment: ok, i was under the impression that you only wanted those posts that had an unread notification on them. but you actually want all the posts, all the time? i think my new edit satisfies that need!

Comment: @DylanCross so go ahead and try it again :)

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, it seems like the code is almooostt there, but I just cannot pinpoint exactly what the problem is, I'm sure if I could explain exactly what it's doing, and what it should be doing you could come up with the answer, (I should be able to come up with it too, but I've been getting frustrated with this query haha). Perhaps if you would like to try to help me get this working exactly right we could speak outside of here and I could give you access to my site for me to better explain what should happen, and what is actually happening. Thanks.

Comment: I think what is happening is it's just not getting the correct "comment" date. I think it would work fine, (or atleast more how i want it to) if there were just simply "GROUP BY N.uniqueID DESC", though there isn't.

Comment: @DylanCross i see. so, what date do you want? if there are two new comments on a post, there would be two new notifications with action 2. let's say that the post is also unread, then there would be three notifications to this one post: one with action 1, and two (both with later dates) with action 2. so, what date should be shown as these posts' notification date?

Comment: @DylanCross i looked at what you'd done previously, and figured that you want post notification date if there is such, and otherwise, the latest comment date. try it now.

Comment: Well Maybe this is What you mean. But it should always be the latest comment date, unless there is no comment available, then just the post date. I will try the code shortly and get back to you. Thanks

Comment: also the code doesn't seem to be doing anything different than the other code was. Thank you very much for you help so far though, very much appreciate it.

Comment: Nevermind, I believe I got it working. thank you for your assistance